# Newbie: Slow Apache2 Response Time, CPU 100%?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu

As the title says I'm a newbie with this stuff but I'm willing to learn what I need to know. I'm simply ignorant atm. This is a Rackspace server with Ubuntu 15.10 running Apache2 using MySQL.

I have a PHP web app that runs with (not yet optimized) good load times on my local machine but stalls for about 2-4 seconds on page load/reload on the server. This seems to be an accumulating stall. The more time that passes the slower it seems to get.

Things I've tried to troubleshoot and other information:

1. I've checked both Chrome network tools and pingdom.com and both reveal that the first initial request is where the longest wait, not local or external resources.
2. Restarting apache helps a little but running the stop then start command seem to temporarily increase load speeds. One thing I noticed here is that I start to get quite a few entries under "CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service" when I run the command "systemctl status apache2.service". I'm not sure if this should indicate anything to me or not. Should I have 10-20+ CGroup entries?
3. I'm peaking at around 250m memory and 100% CPU. No idea why CPU is so high with so few users.
4. Also, if it is pertinent, I am using nodejs, forever and socketio along side Laravel 5 though I don't think that any of this is the culprit for the long wait on the initial response.

What other reports or logs do I need to generate or look at to determine what might be the cause? I've heard some people having an issue with "resource leeching" and others with DDOS. How might I rule something like this out?

Here is a pingdom result of a faster load but still non-optimal. (I know, I need to bundle my scripts and styles ;) )
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/jl6bX/http://barkerbot.com/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your page generation time is high. You need to:

- Optimize your application, or increase CPU resources
- [Page caching](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/caching.html) could reduce the need for optimization, but only for anonymous users. Regenerating pages still takes time. On a busy site caching for even a small number of seconds can reduce server load.
- Set up a CDN (content distribution network) like [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) (which has a free plan). This will reduce the download time for your static resources
- [Change your headers](https://www.howtoforge.com/make-browsers-cache-static-files-with-mod_expires-on-apache2-debian-squeeze) to indicate that static resources should be cached, ideally for a week or more.

You may find this [webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160420_J9_f6d12bd7ee84b6fc26277e225a1dda3c/) test useful. It shows 11 - 15 second page load times - at that level people will be abandoning your website.

We'd need more information about your application and server to help much more.